# Facebook Lead Ads users retrieve

Tags: facebook, api, ads, lead

first of all I expose you my use case:
I have a Facebook application bound with a Facebook page.
I created via Facebook's PowerEditor a Campaign, an AdSet and an Ad all binded to my facebook page(LeadAD).

I sent a LeadAd test campaign and now I would to retrieve the users that completed the form via CURL or maybe PhpSdk.
I can't figure out how to do this, probably I didn't figured out the logic behind Facebook's methods.

I know you can't paste all the code to do this, but if you can, just explain me how the Facebook logic works.
All comments are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that Facebook has some undocumented rest calls.

In this case I was looking for the rest edge "leadgen_forms" callable on **page** or **ad account** ids.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/leadgen_forms?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<PAGE_ID>/leadgen_forms?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

This call allowed me to access the **form** resource id, and calling its own edge I found a lot of useful fields like **leadgen_export_csv_url**, try it with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<FORM_ID>?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

The awesome thing (That was what I was really looking for) was another edge that you can try with this that returns all the leads generated:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<FORM_ID>/leads?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Hope this will help somebody else.

Andrea.